# Erro em gráfico com pacote ggplot2 e função sumarySE

Tags: r, ggplot2

Busco o auxílio de vocês para a solução de alguns problemas na construção de um gráfico com média e erro padrão no R com o pacote ggplot2 e função summarySE.

Em meu trabalho avalio o efeito da competição por recurso entre duas espécies de vertebrados aquáticos com tamanhos diferentes p/g, por meio das variáveis respostas deslocamento PV e deslocamento PH.
Tenho encontrado alguns erros para a execução do script, os apresento logo abaixo.

Agradeço a colaboração de todos. Espero que estes post possa ajudar outros.

Erros:

```
Error1:
gmed <- read.csv("https://drive.google.com/file/d/1X7FEhxjxAVBD-9LB6UrRUd2aMtjcwnyR/view", header = TRUE,sep = ";")

Warning message:
In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
EOF within quoted string

Error 2:
gpv <- summarySE(gmed, measurevar="PV", groupvars=c("INT"))
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : objeto 'INT' não encontrado
```

script do gráfico :

```
gmed <- read.csv("https://drive.google.com/file/d/1X7FEhxjxAVBD-9LB6UrRUd2aMtjcwnyR/view", header = TRUE,sep = ";")

require(Rmisc)
require(ggplot2)

gpv <- summarySE(gmed, measurevar="PV", groupvars=c("INT"))

grafic.gpv <- ggplot(gpv, aes(x=INT, y=PV, fill=INT)) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c("S", "P", "G", "F")) + 
  geom_dotplot(binwidth= 0.5, binaxis="y", stackdir = "center") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=PV-se, ymax=PV+se), width=0.25, size=0.25) +
  labs(x="Tratamentos", y="Posição Vertical (cm)") +
  geom_text(aes(label=paste("N", "==",N,sep = "")), parse = TRUE, y=c(17.5, 15, 15, 22.5)) +
  geom_point(aes(y=PV), size=1, show.legend = F) +
  theme_bw () +
  scale_fill_grey(start=0.25, end=0.75)

grafic.gpv
```

Answer (score 3):

Está a ler mal o ficheiro, uma maneira correta é a seguinte:

```
google_id <- "1X7FEhxjxAVBD-9LB6UrRUd2aMtjcwnyR"
google_file <- sprintf("https://docs.google.com/uc?id=%s&export=download", google_id)
gmed <- read.csv2(google_file)

str(gmed)
#'data.frame':  60083 obs. of  5 variables:
# $ ID     : int  6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 ...
# $ INT    : chr  "S" "S" "S" "S" ...
# $ Tamanho: chr  "P" "P" "P" "P" ...
# $ PV     : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
# $ PH     : num  16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 ...
```

Depois disto, o resto do script, `summarySE` e instruções gráficas, funciona sem problemas.